# bash scripting: how to save find command result to a variable in order to use it in -exec

Tags: file, bash, scripting, filenames

I want to find files and save the file name to a variable and use this variable in -exec in order to do some calculations with it

so for example every time the find returns a file name I use that file name in -exec in order to produce something else at the same time find command finds this file

thanks

Comment: Rather tell us what you are trying to do. This sounds you are not taking it the easiest way around. Also sing `-exec` is also not very efficient.

Comment: hi Tomas, I want to take each file name and search inside for information, for example strings in lines, sentences etc but I want to do this as soon as I find a file that has a specific name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then don't exec.

```
find -whatever |
while read filename; do
    Whatever you did in -exec before "$filename"
    Other thing "$filename"
done
```

This is not robust with file names containing special characters, though.

**Edit**: If you want to do multiple things to the hits returned by `find`, this is certainly possible with `find -exec` or `xargs` as well:

```
find -whatever -exec sh -c 'whatever you did in -exec before {}; other thing {}' \;
```

Or you can mangle the output into a shell script and feed it to `sh`:

```
find -whatever -printf 'mv %p destdir; ln -s destdir/%f %h\n' | sh
```

But if you really, truly want the action to happen as soon as `find` learns about the file, `-exec` is probably the way to go.  (I'm not clear on under what circumstances this would be a useful requirement.  Perhaps you can explain what you want to achieve?)

If you want to keep the list of hits returned by `find` so you can do additional things after `find` finishes, make it output the hits like in the last example, and store the output in a file or pipe it to another command like in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

*"I want to take each file name and search inside for information, for example strings in lines, sentences"* - OK Jonathan, that's what you should have said in your question :-)

Answer:

```
find /dir -iname "*whatever*" | xargs grep 'text'
```

will find text "text" in every file `*whatever*` under directory /dir.

Comment: I don't see how this improves on `find -whatever -exec grep 'text' {} \;` but then I also still don't really feel I understand the question.

Comment: @tripleee, what you've written is a command-line barbarism :P and will get terribly slow for large amount of files - it would execute grep on each file separately! Whereas in my solution the grep is executed by xargs on whole bunches of files.

Comment: I agree, but the main point I am attempting to make is that `xargs` does not help with (what appears to be) the main question; how to do multiple things to each file. You can certainly hack in a shell invocation but you can do that with `find -exec` too.

Comment: @tripleee, I'm not sure this is what the OP asked... I cite his comment in the beginning of my post. If he wanted something else, then it's really hard to guess what he actually wanted...

Comment: Amen to that.  I updated my answer with a lot more speculation.  Let's see if this scattershot approach actually managed to help someone.